# glib gtk - invalid class pointer

Tags: c, class, gtk, glib

I get this error when running my application

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:3119: invalid class pointer `0xdfbb60'
```

It usually happens with a subclass of a `GooCanvasGroup` object being passed to function expection a `GooCanvasItem` (which is a interface class), but it does not fail at that specific point but inside a library.

```
<cut> 
classes : 0xc73cb0 0xc73cb0 
<cut>
classes : 0xff3250 0xff3250 

(oregano:8482): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: gtype.c:3119: invalid class pointer `0x100a330'

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ffff701ba27 in g_logv () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff701ba27 in g_logv () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff701bbf2 in g_log () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff72f1dbd in g_type_interface_peek ()
   from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7baf3dc in goo_canvas_item_update (item=0xb6c490, 
    entire_tree=entire_tree@entry=0, cr=cr@entry=0x7583d0, bounds=bounds@entry=
    0x7fffffffd3b0) at goocanvasitem.c:1698
#4  0x00007ffff7babbaf in goo_canvas_group_update (item=0xb6c370, entire_tree=
    0, cr=0x7583d0, bounds=0x7fffffffd440) at goocanvasgroup.c:615
#5  0x00007ffff7baf3ed in goo_canvas_item_update (item=0xb6c370, 
    entire_tree=entire_tree@entry=0, cr=cr@entry=0x7583d0, bounds=bounds@entry=
    0x7fffffffd440) at goocanvasitem.c:1700
#6  0x00007ffff7babbaf in goo_canvas_group_update (item=0xb6c130, entire_tree=
    0, cr=0x7583d0, bounds=0x7fffffffd4f0) at goocanvasgroup.c:615
#7  0x00007ffff7baf3ed in goo_canvas_item_update (item=0xb6c130, 
    entire_tree=entire_tree@entry=0, cr=cr@entry=0x7583d0, bounds=bounds@entry=
    0x7fffffffd4f0) at goocanvasitem.c:1700
#8  0x00007ffff7bc9425 in goo_canvas_update_internal (canvas=canvas@entry=
    0xc6e0d0, cr=cr@entry=0x7583d0) at goocanvas.c:2560
#9  0x00007ffff7bc9492 in goo_canvas_update (canvas=0xc6e0d0)
    at goocanvas.c:2592
#10 0x00007ffff7baf3a4 in goo_canvas_item_ensure_updated (item=item@entry=
    0xf0e670) at goocanvasitem.c:1676
#11 0x00007ffff7bb46e9 in goo_canvas_item_simple_get_bounds (item=0xf0e670, 
    bounds=0x7fffffffd640) at goocanvasitemsimple.c:1013
#12 0x00007ffff7baf21d in goo_canvas_item_get_bounds (item=0xf0e670, bounds=
    0x7fffffffd640) at goocanvasitem.c:1546
#13 0x000000000043ee77 in create_canvas_items (group=0xde4250, library_part=
    0x8be100) at ../../src/sheet/part-item.c:1176
#14 0x000000000043e841 in part_item_new (sheet=0xc6e0d0, part=0x10095c0)
    at ../../src/sheet/part-item.c:1083
#15 0x0000000000440bff in sheet_item_factory_create_sheet_item (sheet=
    0xc6e0d0, data=0x10095c0) at ../../src/sheet/sheet-item-factory.c:58
#16 0x000000000044730b in sheet_add_ghost_item (sheet=0xc6e0d0, data=0x10095c0)
    at ../../src/sheet/sheet.c:1139
#17 0x000000000042f610 in place_cmd (widget=0xcf9030, br=0xc8bb00)
    at ../../src/part-browser.c:191
#18 0x00007ffff72d3467 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#19 0x00007ffff72ebe66 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
   from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#20 0x00007ffff72ec6b2 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#21 0x00007ffff69db198 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0
#22 0x00007ffff72d3467 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#23 0x00007ffff72ebe66 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
   from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#24 0x00007ffff72ec6b2 in g_signal_emit () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#25 0x00007ffff69d9f03 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0
#26 0x00007ffff6aa8f3f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgtk-3.so.0
#27 0x00007ffff72d3467 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0
#28 0x00007ffff72ebe66 in g_signal_emit_valist ()
```

I verified manually that the class pointer is wrong (read: none of goocanvas, sheet-item, part-item classes)

The last call that puts that issue to surface is

```
            // the group is a "part-item" a subclass of "sheet-item" which is 
            // subclassed from "GooCanvasGroup"
    item = goo_canvas_polyline_new (GOO_CANVAS_ITEM (group), ... );

    g_assert (item!=NULL);
    g_assert (GOO_IS_CANVAS_ITEM (item));

    g_assert (group!=NULL);
    g_assert (GOO_IS_CANVAS_GROUP (group));
    g_assert (GOO_CANVAS_GROUP_GET_CLASS (group)!=NULL);
    g_printf ("classes : %p %p \n", GOO_CANVAS_GROUP_GET_CLASS(group), PART_ITEM_GET_CLASS (group));

    goo_canvas_item_get_bounds (item, &bounds);
```

But as soon as I remove the `goo_canvas_item_...`-call the next call to a `goo_canvas_..` will fail instead.

So my suspect is that something is wrong within the class declarations / type definitions:

sheet-item.c

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE (SheetItem, sheet_item, GOO_TYPE_CANVAS_GROUP)
```

part-item.c

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE (PartItem, part_item, TYPE_SHEET_ITEM)
```

The full files are here:

https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/src/sheet/sheet-item.c
https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/src/sheet/sheet-item.h
https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/src/sheet/part-item.c
https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/src/sheet/part-item.h

I am puzzled what could cause this issue, so any kind of hints are appreciated.

Edit: In case someone wants to try it himself:

```
git clone git://github.com/drahnr/oregano.git
cd oregano
waf configure --prefix=/tmp debug install
gdb ./build/debug/oregano
(gdb) r
## click to time on the "place item"-button on the right side (bottom)
(gdb) bt
```

Comment: You should install the goo canvas debugging symbols so that you can see where in goocanvas the error is coming from

Comment: It is pretty pointless to use debugging symbols of goocanvas, as I then get the exact "crashpoint" within the library but not the bug source (which is the actual issue here - discovering howto trace the root of that bug) - anyways, replaced the backtrace with one including goocanvas debug symbols.

Comment: Actually, the goocanvas debug symbols are useful, because they show that the object that is invalid is not your `item`: In Frame12 your item is `0xf0e670`, but the invalid item in frame3 is `0xb6c490` so it would seem that you are putting some of item into the canvas which is invalid and not the area of code you've shown us.

Comment: I clearly overlooked that *sigh*, thanks a lot!